# Вопрос по С# Перелистывание графика

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Всем привет. Вопрос возможно глупый, но я новичок в с#. В общем в конце кода при нажатии на кнопку необходимо что бы n изменялось на +1 значение. Пробовал написать n++ не помогло

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp25
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Open();
        }
        public void Open()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Файлы |*.dat";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = ofd.FileName;
                GraF1();                
                //  Console.ReadLine();
            }        
        }
        string path;
        public void GraF1()
        {
            int[] glub = new int[500];
            int[,] sp1 = new int[500,500];
            //    int[] spad1 = new int[300];
            //    int[] spad2 = new int[300];
            // string path = @"C:\bin\111.dat";                       
            try
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    //   while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
                    while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
                        {
                            glub[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
                       //     int k;
                       //     for (int n = 0; n <= i; n++)
                         //   {
                             //   k = i * 130;
                                for (int j = 0; j <= 129; j++)
                                {
                                    sp1[i, j] = reader.ReadInt16();
                                }
                         }
                                GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
                                pane.CurveList.Clear();
                                PointPairList list = new PointPairList();                             
                                for (int x = 2; x < 130; x++)
                        {
                            //  int b;
                            // b = x;                                                                       
                            NewMethod(sp1, list, x);
                        }
                                LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve("Спектр", list, Color.Blue, SymbolType.Circle);                                
                                zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
                                // Обновляем график
                                zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                     }
                }                  
            }
            catch (Exception z)
            {
                //   Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(z.Message);
            }
        }
        public void NewMethod(int[,] sp1, PointPairList list, int x)
        {                    
            list.Add(x, sp1[n, x]);            
        }
        public int n = 0;

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Что значит не помогло? Какого эффекта вы ожидаете?

Comment: чтобы после нажатия n становилось 1, после повторного нажатия 2 и т.д.

Comment: `n++` работает нормально. Только вы не сможете увидеть, что n изменилась, вы ведь никуда ее не выводите

Comment: Вот тут пытаюсь вывести ее public void NewMethod(int[,] sp1, PointPairList list, int x)
        {                    
            list.Add(x, sp1[n, x]);            
        }

Comment: В button1_Click MessageBox.Show(); со значением n

Comment: @Dikobraz, ну так вызовите этот метод в обработчике события

Comment: n++ при нажатии работает, только до открытия файла с данными. Т.Е. у меня 10 графиков, и по нажатию должен открываться следующий. Сейчас работает программа так, что n задается до того как я открою график( например нажму 3 раза) и он после выбора файла откроет сразу 3й график. А нужно чтобы n задавалась после. Как сделать?

Comment: Учитесь внятно излагать мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот так:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    n++;
    GraF1();
}
```